# View dependencies of a table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Server Management studio, you can right-click on a table and view its dependencies.

Is there a way to do this in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: What do you mean by "dependencies?"

Comment: Tables, procedures, functions etc which depend upon the table, or which the table depends upon.

Comment: SQLDeveloper has a series of tabs across the top of the right-hand pane when you click on a table name.  That shows columns, constraints, grants, triggers, *dependencies*, indexes, etc.  I'm staring at version 3.2.20.09 as I write this.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you.